# List of Article Submission Directories

Tags: seo, directory, articles

I used to have a link to the top 50 article submission directories arranged by PR, Alexa, and maybe some other factors.  Anyone have this link (and others), that show a ton of article submission directories?

Comment: Article submission has been a real headache. Hopefully this list will give me some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google "list of article submission directories" the site you mentioned comes up first: http://www.vretoolbar.com/articles/directories.php